# array of arraylist type error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, typeerror

```
void radix(int[] arr, int maxDigit){
    int exp = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<maxDigit; i++) {
        ArrayList[] bucket = new ArrayList[10];
        for (int n=0; n<10; n++){
        bucket[n] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
            bucket[(arr[j]%exp)%10].add(arr[j]);
        }

        int ind=0;
        for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
            for (int n : bucket[k]){
                arr[ind] = n;
                ind++; 
            } 
        }
        exp*=10;
    }
}
```

above is my attempt for a radix sort in java. 
I keep having an error at this for loop:

```
for (int n : bucket[k])
```

Saying that Object can't be converted to int.
However, I declared the array to have an arrayList as its element, 
so bucket[k] should be an arraylist.

Can anyone please explain why this happens and how I could get around this problem?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle "Saying that Object can't be converted to int"

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Try using `for(Integer n : bucket[k])`

You also need to provide a type for `ArrayList`. Try `ArrayList<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList[10];`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList[] bucket = new ArrayList[10];`
This does not have the type parameter.
And you should avoid using inflexible, low-level constructs like arrays anyways.
Try to actually express your intents in your code with identifiers and to use first-class objects for all of your key concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ArrayList not ArrayList.

Change:

```
for(int n : bucket[k])
```

To:

```
for(Integer n : bucket[k])
```

You also need to type your ArrayList declaration with:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList<Integer>[];
```

Comment: Would yield the same result since `Object` cannot be automatically converted to `Integer` either.